# Corey Schafer Django (Part 3): HTML not formatting right

Tags: python, html, css, django

So I'm going through Corey Schafer's Django series, and I'm at the part where he is building the HTML template for the website and for some reason it isn't formatting correctly. I downloaded his repository and re-ran his code and still got the same error? The only difference that I can think of is that he is using Django 2.1 and I'm using Django 3.0 but that shouldn't be it.

Here is how it looks:

[image: Picture of wonky formatting]

Here is how it should look:
[image]

And lastly this is his Github for the link: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/03-Templates

Edit: Got it working. You have to do four steps:

**(1) Delete integrity and crossorigin from this line in the base.html (line 11)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

To get this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**(2) Update your static/blog/main.css with this code:**

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #444444;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-steel {
  background-color: #5f788a;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

**(3) Update your templates/blog/home.html with this code:**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**(4) Close your server, and clear your browser from everything (cookies included)**

Comment: I'm unclear on which image is it that you included, but I'll strongly recommend you include both: one for how it should look like, and one for how it turns out to be.

Comment: As crimson said, it would help to have a picture of what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: check if the custom css blog/main.css is being loaded properly in your terminal after the server has been run/re-run. You should see `"GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200` instead of `"GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 400` or anything other than that.

Comment: sorry, i meant `"GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404` not `"GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 400`

Comment: @crimsonpython24 I added the picture of what it should be like

Comment: @AchuthVarghese, I'm getting this: `GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3912`

Comment: there should be a line `"GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200` like this in terminal after server has been run and the page has been loaded. Also, check if file exists in the static/blog folder. Also view your page source and check if you can open the link and view the main.css file in the link tag for main.css stylesheet

Comment: @AchuthVarghese. So I reloaded the page and this came up `"GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0`. The page source has the HTML completely loaded up. I updated my post and included the HTML source of the page instead of the base HTML. I can also view the main.css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I'm fully suspecting something is wrong with your custom css.

First reason: bg-steel is not a default color, so you need to write it somewhere else. However, even with the line below, the navbar didn't show up.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
```

Second reason: for a division to have a border, header, and content with margins applied, you either use a default `card` class or you implement one on your own -- found in this line, which also didn't work.

```html
<article class="media content-section">
```

Third reason: obvious enough, the background colors are different. In your code, it's pure white, which is what bootstrap's default comes with. If the custom sheet is applied, the background color will then look darker.

**Here's what I'll suggest you do:**

1. Go to your HTML or settings.py (if you used `{% load static %}`) file and check whether your static or import paths are correct
2. Go through the video one more time and make sure you have no typos.

As a matter of fact, the javascript files ARE necessary. If you don't include them, things like dropdowns and modals won't work properly.

Comment: I first wrote my own code, and ran into this problem. So I downloaded Corey's code and ran it as is, and it also came up so I don't believe it is a typo issue. An upvoted commented on youtube said this: `Remember to link the 'main.css' AFTER the bootstrap cdn. I spent an hour trying to figure out what was wrong lol`. But I'm not too HTML literate, could that be it and how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think that will be the problem: a direct translation will be "put your custom style behind the bootstrap ones", which you already did. The next thing I'd like you to do for me is to check whether you get the css file successfully in your html document.

Comment: I do, the link to `static/blog/main.css` works and I get this `<main role="main" class="container"> ... </main>`

Comment: But one of the comments above read `GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404` though.

Comment: Oh wow, that was it! I cleared the cookies and reran Corey's code again and it worked. If you edit your post to include that information, I will accept the answer. But my own code isn't working right, so I'm going to have to compare it to Cody's to find the problem. I will post an edit when I do because, at least on youtube, it seems I'm not the only one that has the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**:    A small change in your "main.css" file, add **!important** at the
end of color hash as:

```
.bg-steel {  
  background-color: #5f788a!important;  
}
```

=========================================================

**Explanation**:

You will have to understand the concept of overriding of CSS.
If a component is loading with "!important" in the parent CSS such as:

```
background-color: #5f788a!important;
```

instead of just:

```
background-color: #5f788a;
```

In such cases, you will not be able to override it in your custom/child CSS because **!important** declares it important and **can't be overridden** ***directly***.
However, **you can still override it in the custom CSS** by applying **!important** at the **end of the value of the component** just the way I did above.

====================================================

You may be confused about **Why did it work in Corey's CSS ?**

Answer: The version of bootstrap Corey used in the tutorial was not rendering the **background-color** with the term **!important** at the end and hence he was able to override it directly. But nowadays, bootstrap color classes render with **background-color: #5f788a!important;** and hence can't be overridden directly.

Hope I could help you out.

Thanks

akaroshaa@gmail.com